# Integrating Groovy with Android

Tags: android, groovy

In the past few weeks I've been working on an android app which in its core functionallity relies on a Groovy program I wrote. I want to be able to connect the Groovy project I wrote into my android studio project. Further more, I want to call the main function of the Groovy project from my android activity.

Basically the relationship is like this: 
- Send data from the activity to the Groovy main class
- Groovy does something with that info
- Activity informs the user when the process is ended

But I'm still stuck on how to get these two get along.
I started a new project in android studio in purpose of practicing and playing with groovy and android.

Whenever I try to integrate Groovy into android(GroovyShell, Eval, GroovyScriptEngine, etc...), it throws a `MultipleCompilationErrorsException`

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.silverfix.groovyintegratedapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.util.Eval;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();

        shell.evaluate("3*5");
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime:FATALEXCEPTION:main
Process:com.silverfix.groovyintegratedapp,PID:15604
java.lang.RuntimeException:UnabletostartactivityComponentInfo{com.silverfix.groovyintegratedapp/com.silverfix.groovyintegratedapp.MainActivity}:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:startupfailed:
Generalerrorduringclassgeneration:can'tloadthistypeofclassfile

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:can'tloadthistypeofclassfile
atjava.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
atjava.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:93)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$400(GroovyClassLoader.java:62)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$ClassCollector.createClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:500)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$ClassCollector.onClassNode(GroovyClassLoader.java:517)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$ClassCollector.call(GroovyClassLoader.java:521)
atorg.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:822)
atorg.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1053)
atorg.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
atorg.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
atorg.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:584)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
atgroovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
atcom.silverfix.groovyintegratedapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
atandroid.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
atandroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

1error

atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Causedby:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:startupfailed:
Generalerrorduringclassgeneration:can'tloadthistypeofclassfile

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:can'tloadthistypeofclassfile
atjava.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
atjava.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:93)
```

Comment: I am not certain if the Groovy interpreter works with Android. I think that there are recipes for using the Groovy compiler (`groovyc`) as part of an Android project.

Comment: I haven't found a way to use these two together. Could you please refer me or explain how can I achieve this?